# R - Setting a Frequency to a Document Term Matrix

Tags: r

I am looking for assistance with my R code when exporting a DocumentTermMatrix. The file size is too large to export so I was curious if there is a way to set a Frequency to the DTM? For example, only return values in the DTM that have been used 5 or more times.

`dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(alltextclean)`

`write.csv(as.matrix(dtm), "dtm.csv")`

The above produces too large of a file, can I add a frequency to this? I also tried the below but I am left with a list of terms but without a term count (this would also be useful).

`termsonly <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 5)`

`write.csv(termsonly, "termsonly.csv")`

Adding a frequency to the above would also be helpful.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the total occurrence of each term, across all documents. Using an example dataset:

```
library(tm)
data(crude)
```

If your matrix is not so huge, you can do:

```
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
Freq = colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
```

Otherwise, let's say we take terms with at least 5 occurences:

```
termsonly <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 5)
Freq = colSums(as.matrix(dtm[,termsonly]))
```

Or you cast it into a sparseMatrix and sum the columns:

```
library(Matrix)
Freq = colSums(sparseMatrix(i=dtm$i,j=dtm$j,x=dtm$v,dimnames=dtm$dimnames))
```

You can also check this [post](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidying_casting.html) if you like a tidy solution.

Comment: ```Freq = colSums(as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(crude)))``` This ends up being too large (21.7gb). Is there a way to add instances of terms in 5 or more documents to cut down on the size? I still can't export. ```termsonly <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 5)``` With this code, I would still need a column that shows the number of times that term appeared to sort from highest to lowest (if this is possible) Thanks!

Comment: see updated answer. one of them should work. Once you have the vector, just do ```Freq=sort(Freq)```